# Is a passport required for transit through Narita, Japan (NRT)?

Tags: visas, transit, passports, japan, vietnamese-citizens

I am a Vietnamese Refugee and do not carry a Vietnamese passport. I do however carry a Vietnamese Certificate of Visa Exemption (permission to enter Vietnam) and a green card (to re-enter USA).  I have a three hour layover in Narita and would like to know if allowed to transit without a passport.

If you know, please let me know where you found out. I've been searching high and low and calling everyone I could think of and no one has a certain answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, does "Vietnamese refugee" mean you left Vietnam to live in another country, or that you fled from another country to live in Vietnam?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 You only need to be going somewhere that you do not need a passport to enter the country.

Comment: Do you have any travel document or passport? Is your certificate of visa exemption on a separate paper?

Comment: I don't see how a question about not having a passport is a duplicate of a question of not having a visa, and none of the answers on that question exactly answer this question.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It might not be, but it still needs a lot of clarification from the author.

Comment: Not answering your direct question, but I want to mention that a more important question would be would the airline be willing to let you board the plane 1) on the trip to Vietnam, and 2) on the trip back to the US, in the first place, given the documents you have? Many airlines will refuse to let people on board without a passport or passport-equivalent travel document. If you can't get on the plane, then whether you can transit is moot.

Comment: As a US permanent resident who got permanent residency through being a refugee, you qualify to get either a US Re-entry Permit (valid for 2 years) or a US Refugee Travel Document (valid for 1 year), both of which are documents in booklet form with pages for visas and entry stamps, just like passports, and are recognized for international travel. You may want to look into getting one of these documents.

Answer (score 1):

In principle no one will be interested in your passport during your transit until you get to the departure gate. After you deplane, there is a separate path for international transit that takes you through security, past some check in desks (if you need to check in or get your boarding passes) and straight back upstairs to the international departure lounge, without passing through passport control.

Actually I did an international transit through Narita earlier in the week, and I even took a photograph of the sign.

[image: International transit vs passports sign]

(CI 17 to TPE gets a special sign reminding you that TPE isn't in Japan I think because CI 17 is actually a through flight originating in HNL going via NRT, so there will be a lot of people making that transit, but it is a bit of a quirk there.)

Anyway, the short security queue, shown on the left in this picture, has someone doing a boarding pass or itinerary check, but I think that's mostly to ensure you don't go the wrong way. It's an airport helper staff not Japanese border security. I found my onward itinerary on my phone (I wasn't checked in because this was across onto a separate ticket) and that was enough to reassure her, although she did find it odd I hadn't printed it out, but I don't think I showed my passport.

Now, as for the bureaucracy, will the Japanese government allow this transit on a refugee document? I think that is close to the "Do I need a visa?" suggested duplicate above. But if you specify the origin and destination countries of your journey I can try to pull it up on TIMATIC.